# how to access textbox and checkbox values inside Gridview using JQuery

Tags: jquery, datagrid

how to access textbox values inside Gridview using JQuery

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".gridViewCss").find("input[@type=checkbox]").each(function(){
     if(this.checked){
         alert(Checkbox Checked);
     }
    else
    {
          alert(Checkbox not Checked);
    }
});
```

Here gridViewCss is CSS class assigned to grid.